# Display text - text from Function to display in Class

Tags: python, function, class, oop, tkinter

I have the following piece of code: I am trying to get the text from function loadFile() to actually appear in the tkinter text display in class DiagramFrame.
When I run the code, I choose the file and this error comes out:

"AttributeError: type object 'DiagramFrame' has no attribute 'fileDisplayText'"

and the text cannot be displayed at the tkinter window.

This is the code:

```
class DiagramFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        frame_right = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_right.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='both', expand=True)

        label1 = tk.Label(frame_right, text="Drawing Plotter view", anchor='w', padx=0, pady=0)  # font=("Verdana", 12))
        label1.pack(side=TOP, fill='both')

        self.f = Figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=100)
        self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        self.a.plot(0, 0, 'r')
        self.a.plot(0, 0, 'g')
        self.a.axis("equal")
        self.a.grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, frame_right)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both', expand=True)

        #self.plot(Data)

        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        frame_left = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_left.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        label2 = tk.Label(frame_left, text="Gcode view", anchor='w', padx=0, pady=0)  # font=("Verdana", 9))
        label2.pack(side=TOP, fill='both')

        frame_bottomleft = tk.Frame(frame_left)
        frame_bottomleft.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        # self.loadFile(selectedfilepath)
        self.fileDisplayScrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_bottomleft)
        self.fileDisplayText = Text(frame_bottomleft, width=27, font=(9))
        self.fileDisplayText.pack(side=LEFT, fill='both', expand=True)  # anchor='w',
        self.fileDisplayScrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)  # , expand=True)
        self.fileDisplayScrollbar.config(command=self.fileDisplayText.yview)
        self.fileDisplayText.config(yscrollcommand=self.fileDisplayScrollbar.set)

def do_line(line):
    try:
        g = GCode.parse_line(line)
        res = machine.do_command(g)
    except (GCodeException, GMachineException) as e:
        print('ERROR ' + str(e))
        return False
    if res is not None:
        print('OK ' + res)
    else:
        print('OK')
    return True

def quit():
    sys.exit(0)


def browseFile():
    global selectedfilepath
    tmp = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="./", title="select gcode file", filetypes=(
        ("gcode files", "*.gcode"), ("gio files", "*.gio"), ("nc files", "*.nc"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    selectedfilepath = tmp
    loadFile()


def loadFile():
    logging_config.debug_disable()
    try:
        DiagramFrame.fileDisplayText.delete("1.0", tkinter.END)
        if 'selectedfilepath' in globals():
        #if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            # Read file with gcode
            with open(selectedfilepath, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    line = line.strip()
                    #print('> ' + line)
                    DiagramFrame.fileDisplayText.insert(tkinter.INSERT, '> ' + line)
                    if not do_line(line):
                        break
        else:
            # Main loop for interactive shell
            # Use stdin/stdout, additional interfaces like
            # UART, Socket or any other can be added.
            print("*************** Testing testing 123 ***************")
            while True:
                line = raw_input('> ')
                if line == 'quit' or line == 'exit':
                    break
                do_line(line)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    print("\r\nExiting...")
    machine.release()

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Why does it happened and what should i do to correct it?

p/s: i'm still learning and not so much understanding about class and object

Comment: i'd encourage you to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

Comment: You need to create an instance of `DiagramFrame` and use it to access the text box.